# Ignoring blocks of text with Docco

Tags: gruntjs, docco

Using Docco (latest) via Grunt (grunt-docco) against JavaScript code.  How can blocks of text be ignored?  For example, at the top of all JavaScript files is license info in multi-line comments:

```
/**
   Copyright 2014....
*/
```

Or let's say I have code that I do not what Docco to process?